# Reader's choice to interpret the story as he wishes to

Tags: phrase-usage

Many times stories end in a way that the reader has a choice to decide which interpretation he'd like to follow. What is the word or phrase one should use to describe this situation?

It is analogous to the poetic liberty that poets have to coin new words and stuff.

Comment: ***ambiguous***?

Answer (score 1):

"Reader's prerogative" perhaps?

Comment: Sounds good though not sure

Comment: "License," perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

[*Dangler*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangler_(plot_device)) is a plot device in which some plot line is never resolved. In this case you care about the ending, so it is a *dangler ending*, open ending.